# Shortest Path Maximum Profit

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Suppose you have an undirected Graph G=(V,E) and two vertices s,t in V, s not equal t. Every Edge e in E has a length and a profit.

The problem is:
How can I find a path P=(s,a1,a2,...,t) between s-t such that the total length of the path is the minimum possible and the profit is the maximum possible. 
With Dijkstra I can find the first constraint, but How can I be sure for the second one?

You can do a backtrack but, Is there any faster algorithm? Any help is welcome.

EDIT:
First find the value x of the shortest path, then over the set of all the
paths with the same length x, find one with the maximum profit.

See this picture: [image]

Comment: What is your criteria? Minimum Length or Maximum Profit? If minimum length does not have maximum profit, which will you choose?

Comment: Is this even possible ? Nothing guarantees that the absolute minimum path length will match the absolute maximum profit path. If you have a valuation function (rank a path according to its length and profit) then you could use A*. If you have not then you must find a compromise between path length and profit. An easy one would be to take all of the paths with the minimum length (if there are several), then choose the one which maximise profit.

Comment: @AbdulFatir First find the value x of the shortest path, then over the set of all the paths with the same length x, find one with the maximum profit.

Comment: Use pointwise addition and lexicographic comprisons over the weight vectors (lenght, -cost). The rest remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing a single value for each candidate path in Dijkstra's algorithm, store a tuple of (total length, total profit). Consider a path shorter in the relaxation step if the total length is less, or the total lengths are the same but the total profit is higher.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing is you have two arrays maintaining length and profit respectively.
You can create another array which will ratio of length to profit of edges. 
So the array will store ratio = length/profit for all edges and the using this ration array, you can use Djikshtra's algorithm.
For Djikshtra's algorithm, use V set as vertex and array ratio. Using this run Djikshtra's algorithm. You will get your required answer

Comment: Dijkstra is about finding the shortest distance, you're actually describing A* (which is like Dijkstra, but uses a heuristic instead of the mere distance). Here, your heuristic is the ratio.

Comment: @T.Claverie, Feel free to correct me if I wrong but if I use an Heuristic it is possible to get a not optimal solution.

Comment: You're right. For the solution you expect, heuristic is the wrong way to go because it will hardly give you anything but sub-optimal solutions. Just find all the paths of minimum length with Dijkstra and select the one with maximum profit, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an example of [multi-objective optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization).

One way to approach such a problem is to make a new variable, `L` for lambda.

But first, let's deal with the profit issue: Your edges have lengths `l` and profits `p`. Redefine all of the `p` such that `p'=max(p)-p`. Now, your maximally profitable edge has a value of zero (lowest possible) and your least-profitable edge has a value of `max(p)` (highest possible). You can now find the least cost-path.

Define the weight of an edge as being `l*L+p'*(1-L)`, now vary `L` from 0 to 1. Different paths will be optimal depending on whether the length or profit is more important. Loosely speaking, these paths form a Pareto optimal set. Each solution path is better than all others for that particular value of `L`. For that `L` there is no way to increase profit without also increasing length, or to decrease length without decreasing profit.

Note that choosing appropriate values of `L` to generate this set may not be straight-forward: for instance, if profit numbers are much larger than length numbers, most of the set will cluster in values of `L` which scale the profit values to a level where they are comparable with the length values. These `L` values may be quite small.

Ooop, saw your edit: "First find the value x of the shortest path, then over the set of all the paths with the same length x, find one with the maximum profit." In this case, [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339502/752843) is the way to go.